# Why is this CountIf function returning "0"?

Tags: excel, vba, countif

**The actual situation**

I have a master workbook (Wb) with a user form - file explorer (Screenshot 1) and a Sheet2 for the results (Screenshot 2)

I have a source workbook, which has a huge amount of data(14k rows) and is quite frankly a mess.. For my calculation only 2 columns of the source workbook are relevant: column 8 (True Dates) and colum 30 (numerical values).
**Important note regarding column 8** : only the rows with the first of every month is relevant for me. Meaning: 01.01., 01.02.,01.03.,01.04. etc. Every other row should be ignored.

I use the Wb to search for the source workbook(wb.Source) to apply the following calculations:

**Task 1**: calculating the avarage value if certain conditions are met

**Task 2**: counting rows if the following conditions are met:

- If a row in ws.Source has date in Column 8 = "01.01" and numerical value in Column 30 is < 50 then count and enter the result in cell B8 in Sheet 2 of Wb
- If a row in ws.Source has date in Column 8= "01.01" and Column 30 is > 50 and < 100 then count and enter the result in cell B9 in Sheet 2 of Wb
- If a row in ws.Source has date in Column 8= "01.01" and Column 30 is > 100 then count and enter the result in cell B10 in Sheet 2 of Wb

This should be applied for every month.

The results are then added to my Wb Sheet2.

**My problems/questions**

**1.** Regarding Task 2: My CountIf function results in "0" for every month and I don't know why? See attached screenshots from my result sheet of Wb(Screenshot 2) and an example of rows of my wb.Source.(Screenshot 3)

**2.** Regarding Task 1: the calculation works so far, but how can I make sure that only the rows with the first of every month are considered and everything else ignored?

**3.** Is it possible to restrict the scope of the calculation in the sense that only the past 12 months are calculated, starting from a certain date (counting back). Meaning: To set a Date (Month/Year) in my user form and consider only the rows of the past 12 months for the calculation? If no date is set then "today" should be the starting point. I think the Const = YEAR has to be removed from the code, as there is definitely the possibility that the wb.Source contains rows from different years.

I would appreciate any help!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() ' select file    
    Dim fname As Variant
    With Me
        fname = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel File(s) (*.xls*),*.xls*", , "Select FIle", , False)
        If fname <> "False" Then .TextBox1.Text = fname
    End With
End Sub

'calculate avarage
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click() ' update averages
    Const YEAR = 2019

    ' open source workbook
    Dim fname As String, wbSource As Workbook, wsSource As Worksheet
    fname = Me.TextBox1.Text

    If Len(fname) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No file selected", vbCritical, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(fname, False, True) ' no link update, read only
    Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets("Sheet1") ' change to suit

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet2") '

    ' scan down source workbook calc average
    Dim iRow As Long, lastRow As Long
    Dim sMth As String, iMth As Long
    Dim count(12) As Long, sum(12) As Long

    lastRow = wsSource.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For iRow = 1 To lastRow
        If IsDate(wsSource.Cells(iRow, 8)) _
                And IsNumeric(wsSource.Cells(iRow, 30)) Then
            iMth = Month(wsSource.Cells(iRow, 8))   ' col H
            sum(iMth) = sum(iMth) + wsSource.Cells(iRow, 30) ' Col AD
            count(iMth) = count(iMth) + 1
        End If
    Next

    'calculate number of rows (CountIf)
    Dim x As Long
    Dim m As Variant

    For x = 1 To 12
        m = "01." & Format(x, "00")

        ws.Cells(8, 1 + x) = _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(wsSource.Columns(8), m & "*", _
        wsSource.Columns(30), "<=" & 50)

        ws.Cells(9, 1 + x) = _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(wsSource.Columns(8), m & "*", _
        wsSource.Columns(30), ">" & 50, wsSource.Columns(30), "<=" & 100)

        ws.Cells(10, 1 + x) = _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(wsSource.Columns(8), m & "*", _
        wsSource.Columns(30), ">" & 100)
    Next x

    ' close source worbook no save
    wbSource.Close False

    ' update Sheet 2 with averages
    With ws.Range("A3")
        For iMth = 1 To 12
            .Offset(0, iMth - 1) = MonthName(iMth) & " " & YEAR
            If count(iMth) > 0 Then
                .Offset(1, iMth - 1) = sum(iMth) / count(iMth)
                .Offset(1, iMth - 1).NumberFormat = "0.0"
            End If
        Next
    End With

    Dim msg As String
    msg = iRow - 1 & " rows scanned in " & TextBox1.Text
    MsgBox msg, vbInformation, "Sheet 2 updated"
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are your dates true dates or are they text strings that look like dates?

Comment: They are true dates.